# Serve Next build from Python

Tags: javascript, python, http, next.js, server

I have a Next JS app, I need to serve it from python using libraries like Flask or http.server.

I add   `output: 'export'` to the next.config.js and run `yarn build`.

After that, according the documentation (https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/deploying/static-exports), the full exported app should be in the out directory.

When I run `python -m http.server` in the directory, I get
[image: Browser error].
What is wrong ? Thanks a lot.